# What best way to populate java list with separate elements and elements from other lists?

Tags: java, list, collections, linked-list

I need to create a linked list and populate it with "containers" and "elements" from containers.

This is my code:

```
public List<WebElement> getExpectedElements(){
    List<WebElement> list = new LinkedList<WebElement>(Arrays.asList(
            inetConnection,
            wiredConnection,
            phonesConnection,
            usbConnection,
            wifiConnection
    ));
    list.addAll(inetConnection.getExpectedElements());
    list.addAll(wiredConnection.getExpectedElements());
    list.addAll(phonesConnection.getExpectedElements());
    list.addAll(usbConnection.getExpectedElements());
    list.addAll(wifiConnection.getExpectedElements());
    return list;
}
```

Is there any way in java to make it nicer (more laconic, DRY, etc.) ?

Comment: Can you pass around the list to the objects populating it?

Comment: What do you mean by "nicer?"

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It's not correspondent to that objects' responsibility... At least in my objects model...

Comment: @yashaka All you would have to change is how the `List` returned by, for example, `inetConnection.getExpectedElements()`, gets initialized.

Comment: @RobertHarvey
I mean shorter, more laconic, more DRY...
The following python code would be at least shorter:)
........
`list = [[con] + con.getExpectedElements for con in [inetCon, wiredCon, phonesCon, usbCon, wifiCon]]; return reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, list) #or: return sum(list, [])`
.........
Maybe this is not perfect, but a bit nicer than java code in the subj:)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis
You mean at least overload getExpectedElements with a version taking the list to be joined with the result of 'old' getExpectedElements() and to be returned, don't you?
This way I walk threw all elements and construct a list i want...
But again... I'll need one more method to create a list of initial containers... Because there is no way to create list like [inetCon, usbCon, ... ] in java...

Comment: @yashaka When you create your `xyzConnection` objects, just pass them the reference to the list you want the expected elements to populate. The list is basically a global list (careful synchronizing it) that every element adds to.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Oh, it seems to be not like that easy in my case... Because I am not creating directly my connection objects... I extend general 'Container' class, that handle all creation stuff by itself, including the usage of annotations on its childs... Or something like this... But I got your idea... Will think about it. Thanks!

Comment: Otherwise, I don't think anyone sees anything wrong with your current solution.

Comment: That's also good to know! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could at least introduce a loop:

```
List<WebElement> containers = Arrays.asList(inetConnection,
        wiredConnection,
        phonesConnection,
        usbConnection,
        wifiConnection);
List<WebElement> list = new LinkedList<WebElement>(containers);
for (WebElement e : containers)
    list.addAll(e.getExpectedElements());
```

Comment: That would be better option, if my WebElements have .getExpectedElements() method... But only 'containers' implement HaveExpectedElements interface and have this method... Making result list of LIst<HaveExpectedElements> would be not enough to me, because I need some WebElement's operations on the elements of the list.